# Skype crashes on Windows 8.1

Tags: crash, skype, windows-8.1

I installed skype for desktop on windows 8,1.
It seemed it worked fine but it continues to crash and to use tons of resources.

How could it be?

Comment: Have you tried to [google](https://www.google.com/#q=skype+crashes+on+windows+8) it first?

Comment: @blurstream - Place skype in logging mode so it will generate a log file this will allow you to determine what is causing the problem. If I were to hazard a guess its a driver problem.  Does the Skype on the Windows Store crash also?  I was able to figure out how to solve my own problem with Skype because of the Modern UI version of it.

Comment: I tried to downgrade the version to 6.9.x.x and now it does't use resources awfully. Probably the last is a bugged version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype has an internal database, and is sensitive if it is damaged or has some incompatibility problems.

Delete the folder C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Skype [warn: all of your skype data will be lost], and try to start skype now.

It is better if you create a new account first, and try to run skype on it. If it runs, should you do this only.

Comment: I tried to delete it but I experience the same issue. thank you!

Comment: Problem solved! I think there is a bug in the last version. With version 6,9,0,106 it runs smooth!